# How to correctly connect a MicroSD card to an FPGA device

Tags: fpga, sd

I want to ask how to correctly connect a MicroSD card to an FPGA device(not spi version), consider all FPGA pins will be floating for an amount of time before FPGA is configured. I've found a lot of different configurations with MCU, like SPI version, all pin with pull up, some pins with pull down, resistors on some lines ecc.. many are for SD and not MicroSD(I don't know if this matter).

Can someone tell me a working wiring that is compatible with all MicroSD?(Possibily tested)

Comment: You can look into schematics of existing FPGA prototyping or development boards. They are also called reference designs, because develops can have a look how to solve the integration of FPGAs and how to realized connectivity.

Comment: I've tryed, but found only SD card adapter for FPGA or MicroSD with SPI inderface.

Comment: For many FPGAs the default pin state is Input with weak pull-up. Accessing a filesystem on an SD card would be a somewhat tricky bit of firmware to develop, and it is easier and cheaper (time is money) to simply use an interface chip for the (micro)SD card. The only difference between microSD and SD is mechanical - they are electrically the same.

Comment: SD card specifications can be found here https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/pls/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During normal operations, CLK is always driven, whereas CMD and DATA are bidirectional.
CMD must be pulled-up as frames begin with a low start bit and end with a high stop bit.

DATA[0] is used as a busy signal and must also be pulled high.

The other data lines DATA[1:3] could be left unconnected, but it is better when CMOS I/O are not left in high impedance 'middle' state. A pullup or weak keeper should be used, the ones inside the FPGA may be enough.

As long as the clock does not oscillate much during power-up, it could be left as-is. There is a long initialization sequence needing many clock cycles (at 400kHz...) anyway.

Pull-ups in FPGAs are usually not meant for polarizing external components, only the FPGA own pins. So an external resistor is better.

Serial resistors (for example 50 ohms) allow to reduce overshoots and glitches. It is particularly useful for the clock. You could also set a low output current to the FPGA pins (but it will degrade the Tdo delay).

Finally, SD to microSD adapters are entirely passive (like PCMCIA to CompactFlash adapters...)

There are some explanations in this old SanDisk document : http://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/General/SDSpec.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the following part [ECLAMP2410P](http://www.semtech.com/images/datasheet/eclamp2410p.pdf) which is a protection devices intended for microSD cards with pull-ups included.

There pull-ups are on DAT[0..3] and CMD but not on CLK.